# Check difference between two dates using XSLT

Tags: xpath, xslt-2.0

1]I have below input xml1:

```
<TimeLimit Start="2022-02-24" End="2022-03-04"/>
<Tasks>
  <TaskRate RateCode="Test">
    <Rates>
       <Rate BeginDate="2022-02-24" EndDate="2022-02-25" >
        <Base Amount="100.00" CurrencyCode="EUR"/>
       </Rate>
      <Rate BeginDate="2022-02-26" EndDate="2022-03-01" >
       <Base Amount="200.00" CurrencyCode="EUR"/>
      </Rate>
      <Rate BeginDate="2022-03-02" EndDate="2022-03-03" >
       <Base Amount="200.00" CurrencyCode="EUR"/>
      </Rate>
   </Rates>
  </TaskRate>
</Tasks>
```

I want output as below:

```
<TimeLimit Start="2022-02-24" End="2022-03-04"/>
<Tasks>
  <TaskRate RateCode="Test">
    <Rates>
       <Rate BeginDate="2022-02-24" EndDate="2022-02-25" >
        <Base Amount="100.00" CurrencyCode="EUR"/>
       </Rate>
      <Rate BeginDate="2022-02-25" EndDate="2022-03-02" >
       <Base Amount="200.00" CurrencyCode="EUR"/>
      </Rate>
      <Rate BeginDate="2022-03-02" EndDate="2022-03-04" >
       <Base Amount="200.00" CurrencyCode="EUR"/>
      </Rate>
   </Rates>
  </TaskRate>
</Tasks>
```

2]And when i have below input xml2:

```
<TimeLimit Start="2022-02-24" End="2022-03-04"/>
<Tasks>
  <TaskRate RateCode="Test">
    <Rates>
       <Rate BeginDate="2022-02-24" EndDate="2022-02-26" >
        <Base Amount="100.00" CurrencyCode="EUR"/>
       </Rate>
      <Rate BeginDate="2022-02-26" EndDate="2022-03-02" >
       <Base Amount="200.00" CurrencyCode="EUR"/>
      </Rate>
      <Rate BeginDate="2022-03-02" EndDate="2022-03-04" >
       <Base Amount="200.00" CurrencyCode="EUR"/>
      </Rate>
   </Rates>
  </TaskRate>
</Tasks>
```

Then i want output as below:

```
<TimeLimit Start="2022-02-24" End="2022-03-04"/>
<Tasks>
  <TaskRate RateCode="Test">
    <Rates>
       <Rate BeginDate="2022-02-24" EndDate="2022-02-26" >
        <Base Amount="100.00" CurrencyCode="EUR"/>
       </Rate>
      <Rate BeginDate="2022-02-26" EndDate="2022-03-02" >
       <Base Amount="200.00" CurrencyCode="EUR"/>
      </Rate>
      <Rate BeginDate="2022-03-02" EndDate="2022-03-04" >
       <Base Amount="200.00" CurrencyCode="EUR"/>
      </Rate>
   </Rates>
  </TaskRate>
</Tasks>
```

That means for continuous or non continuous date range as input i always want a output xml with continuous date range.
I am using below XSLT code, but its not working:

```
<Rates>
<xsl:for-each select="Rates/Rate">
<Rate>
<xsl:if test="@BeginDate and not(@BeginDate='')">
<xsl:attribute name="BeginDate">
<xsl:value-of select="@BeginDate" />
</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:if>
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="(xs:date(following-sibling::Rate[1]/@BeginDate) - xs:date(@EndDate)) = 1">
<xsl:attribute name="EndDate">
<xsl:value-of select="xs:date(@EndDate)+xs:dayTimeDuration('P1D')" />
</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
<xsl:if test="@EndDate and not(@EndDate='')">
<xsl:attribute name="EndDate">
<xsl:value-of select="@EndDate" />
</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="xs:date(/TimeLimit/@End) - @EndDate = 1">
<xsl:attribute name="EndDate">
<xsl:value-of select="xs:date(@EndDate)+xs:dayTimeDuration('P1D')" />
</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
<xsl:if test="@EndDate and not(@EndDate='')">
<xsl:attribute name="EndDate">
<xsl:value-of select="@EndDate" />
</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>

</Rate>
</xsl:for-each>
</Rates>
```

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the following xslt I made 2 assumptions:

Dates can differ more than just one day and TimeLimit/@start should also be respected. Then no date-calculation is needed. Please let me know if that is correct?

Since your xml did not had a root-element, this is xml I used:

```
<TasksGroup>
  <TimeLimit Start="2022-02-24" End="2022-03-04"/>
  <Tasks>
    <TaskRate RateCode="Test">
      <Rates>
        <Rate BeginDate="2022-02-24" EndDate="2022-02-25" >
          <Base Amount="100.00" CurrencyCode="EUR"/>
        </Rate>
        <Rate BeginDate="2022-02-26" EndDate="2022-03-01" >
          <Base Amount="200.00" CurrencyCode="EUR"/>
        </Rate>
        <Rate BeginDate="2022-03-02" EndDate="2022-03-03" >
          <Base Amount="200.00" CurrencyCode="EUR"/>
        </Rate>
      </Rates>
    </TaskRate>
  </Tasks>  
</TasksGroup>
```

And this the xslt

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
  
  <xsl:output method="xml"  encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
  
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:variable name="timeLimt" as="element()" select="/*/TimeLimit[1]"/>

  <xsl:template match="Rate">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="position()=1">
          <xsl:attribute name="BeginDate">
            <xsl:value-of select="$timeLimt/@Start" />
          </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="@BeginDate[not(.='')]">
          <xsl:copy-of select="@BeginDate"/>
        </xsl:when>
      </xsl:choose>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="position()=last()">
          <xsl:attribute name="EndDate">
            <xsl:value-of select="$timeLimt/@End" />
          </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="following-sibling::*[1][@BeginDate[not(.='')]]">
          <xsl:attribute name="EndDate">
            <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::*[1]/@BeginDate" />
          </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="@EndDate[not(.='')]">
          <xsl:copy-of select="@EndDate"/>
        </xsl:when>
      </xsl:choose>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

results in this:

```
<TasksGroup>
   <TimeLimit Start="2022-02-24" End="2022-03-04"/>
   <Tasks>
      <TaskRate RateCode="Test">
         <Rates>
            <Rate BeginDate="2022-02-24" EndDate="2022-02-26">
               <Base Amount="100.00" CurrencyCode="EUR"/>
            </Rate>
            <Rate BeginDate="2022-02-26" EndDate="2022-03-02">
               <Base Amount="200.00" CurrencyCode="EUR"/>
            </Rate>
            <Rate BeginDate="2022-03-02" EndDate="2022-03-04">
               <Base Amount="200.00" CurrencyCode="EUR"/>
            </Rate>
         </Rates>
      </TaskRate>
   </Tasks>
</TasksGroup>
```

Comment: Did this answer your question?